# Specifying per-table permissions in Google cloud bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I have a Google cloud bigtable deployment with several tables. Is there a way to create service accounts with table-level granularity in permissions?

For example, I have two jobs A and B such that
1. job A only gets read and write access to table T1 (via service account Sa); and
2. job B gets read and write access to table T2 but only read access for table T1 (via service account Sb).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently supported.  We do understand the importance of this use case.

Comment: @les-vogel-google-devrel, is there a plan or timeline to make this publicly available?

Comment: @RohitSaboo – we don't have a timeline for this feature at this time, but happy to chat about it with you further offline.